# Global Variable not able to be accessed in function?

Tags: programming, variables

I am trying to compile an Arduino program that takes analog input. However, when I declare multiple global variables, it often will not compile and because it throws an error that the variables aren't within scope of the functions within the program. I am not super familiar with Arduino IDE, but this doesn't programmatically make sense to me.

This is the program:

```
/*
*  By Hannah Perner-Wilson, www.plusea.at
*  Modified 3/30/2012 By Brian E Kaminski, www.AdvancerTechnologies.com
*
*  IMPORTANT!!:
*  Scroll down to set your serial port
*  Scroll down to set your thresholds
*/

import processing.serial.*;

// definition of window size
// you can change the size of the window as you like
// the thresholdGraph will be scaled to fit
// the optimal size for the thresholdGraph is 1000 x 400
int xWidth = 1200;
int yHeight = 750;

// xPos input array, using prefix
int[] xPosArr= {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

// 
int[] messageArr= {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

// Arrays for threshholding
int[] threshMax= {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
int[] threshMin= {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 

// variables for serial connection. portname and baudrate are user specific
Serial port1;

//Set your serial port here (look at list printed when you run the application once)
String V3 = Serial.list()[1];
String portname1 = V3;
int baudrate = 9600;

int prefix = 10001;
boolean myCatch = false;
String serialIN = "";
String serialINPUT = ""; 
String buffer = ""; 
int value = 0; 

// ThresholdGraph draws grid and poti states
ThresholdGraph in;

void setup(){
  // set size and framerate
  size(xWidth, yHeight);
  frameRate(25);
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(5);
  stroke(0);
  smooth();
  strokeCap(ROUND);

  // establish serial port connection      
  port1 = new Serial(this, portname1, baudrate);
  port1.bufferUntil('\n') ;
  println(Serial.list());  // print serial list

  // create DisplayItems object
  in = new ThresholdGraph();

  // THRESHOLD VALUES:
  // using the thresholdGraph you can determine the MIN and MAX values
  // of your sensors. Enter these here. They must lie between 0 and 1000.

    //MIN trashhold
    threshMin[0] = 20;   // one
    threshMin[1] = 20;   // two
    threshMin[2] = 20;   // three
    threshMin[3] = 20;   // four
    threshMin[4] = 20;   // five
    threshMin[5] = 20;   // six

    //MAX trashhold
    threshMax[0] = 600;   // one
    threshMax[1] = 600;   // two
    threshMax[2] = 600;   // three
    threshMax[3] = 600;   // four
    threshMax[4] = 600;   // five
    threshMax[5] = 600;   // six
}//end setup

// draw listens to serial port, draw 
void draw(){

  // listen to serial port and trigger serial event  
  while(port1.available() > 0){
        serialIN = port1.readStringUntil('\n');
        //println((int)float(serialIN));
        if(serialIN != "")
          serialEvent(serialIN);  
        else
          Serial.println("found empty");
        }

  // threshold serial input  
  threshHolding();  

  // draw serial input
  in.update();
}//end draw()
```

The error that are being thrown are:

```
testproject.ino:100:17: error: 'threshHolding' was not declared in this scope
testproject.ino:103:3: error: 'in' was not declared in this scope
Error compiling.
```

Comment: Looks more like a Processing sketch. Where is the `threshHolding` function defined? (PS `threshHolding` and `in` are functions, not variables)

Comment: Agreed. It looks like that's a Processing sketch which was written to communicate with an Arduino. Perhaps the wrong code was added to the question?

Comment: I thought that "processing.serial" does not need to be imported in a .ino code?

Comment: Can anyone answer why that has been written ?

Comment: @Gerben , Do you know why?

Comment: Or @PeterR.Bloomfield , do you know?

Comment: @Mathsman100 It's there because this is a Processing sketch, not Arduino. `import` is a Java keyword which doesn't exist in C++, so it won't work in the Arduino IDE.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield ,   But I thought the sketch is saved as a .ino, so it should work just like one that is written using Arduino IDE?

Comment: @Mathsman100 It's not really feasible to convert Java code to C++ automatically for microcontroller programming. The result would probably be very inefficient at best.

Comment: The @rsheeler might have done a mistake in that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is not an Arduino Sketch, but a processing file which is noted by the initial import statement that is Java based. Because the Arduino IDE is not very sophisticated, it didn't shout out obvious errors such as `import type not defined` or even `ThresholdGraph` not defined.

To use this file it is necessary to use the following IDE: https://processing.org/reference/environment/